# SQL Server XML select node having highest value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyObjects](
    [Id] [bigint],
    [Details] [xml])
```

content of XML column:

```
<Objects>
    <List>
        <e>
            <Name>Standard bike</Name>
            <Value>300</Value>
        </e>
        <e>
            <Name>Super bike</Name>
            <Value>1000</Value>
        </e>
    </List>
</Objects>
```

How do I select an object name with highest value?

This is as far as I went:

```
SELECT Id, objectDetails.e.value('(Name/text())[1]','varchar(max)')  as 'most expensive object'
FROM MyObjects
CROSS APPLY MyObjects.Details.nodes('/Objects/List/e') objectDetails(e)
```

Ps. If you know more effitient way then CROSS APPLY then let me know

Comment: Couple of side notes, `varchar(MAX)` isn't a one size fits all data type; is your node `Name` *really* likely to have *over* 8,000 characters? Also, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a FLWOR expression containing an `order by`. You need to cast your value to `xs:int` first, otehrwise it will be interpreted as text.

```sql
SELECT
  Id,
  objectDetails.e.value('(Name/text())[1]','varchar(max)')  as [most expensive object]
FROM MyObjects
CROSS APPLY MyObjects.Details.nodes('
   (
    for $e in /Objects/List/e
    order by xs:int(($e/Value/text())[1]) descending
    return $e
   )[1]
  ') objectDetails(e);
```

If you just want a single value from the XML, you can place the whole thing inside `.value`. This will generally be faster for a single one, but slower if you need multiple `.values`.

```sql
SELECT
  Id,
  Details.value('
  (
    for $e in /Objects/List/e
    order by xs:int(($e/Value/text())[1]) descending
    return $e/Name/text()
   )[1]','varchar(max)')  as [most expensive object]
FROM MyObjects;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c50813849eefd56064edc4402f203a3f)

Answer (score 1):

Xpath max() is an option and get the Name either with values() or cross apply if there are multiple nodes with Value = max(Value).

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyObjects](
    [Id] [bigint],
    [Details] [xml]);
    
insert into myobjects(id, details) values(1, '<Objects>
    <List>
        <e>
            <Name>Standard bike</Name>
            <Value>300</Value>
        </e>
        <e>
            <Name>Super bike</Name>
            <Value>1000</Value>
        </e>
        <e>
            <Name>Super bike X</Name>
            <Value>1000</Value>
        </e>
    </List>
</Objects>')



select Id, Details.value('(/Objects/List/e[Value[text() = max(/Objects/List/e/Value/text())]]/Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') 
from MyObjects;

select Id, n.e.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'), n.e.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'int')
from MyObjects as m
cross apply m.Details.nodes('/Objects/List/e[Value[text() = max(/Objects/List/e/Value/text())]]') as n(e);
```